# Babel module build failed when passing multiple presets into create-react app package.json

Tags: javascript, babeljs, create-react-app

I have the following package.json config(babel options are at the bottom):

```
{
  "name": "react-tea-timer",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "detect-port": "1.1.0",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "3.16.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.6.2",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.42.0",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.3",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.2",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.5.2",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^3.1.9",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
    "rc-slider": "^6.3.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-blur-image-loader": "^0.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>[/\\\\](build|docs|node_modules|scripts)[/\\\\]"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "mobx"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "homepage": "https://shooshte.github.io/teaTimer/"
}
```

Now according to the [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets) this is the correct way to pass in multiple presets, but I am still getting the following error when running npm run start:

> Error in ./src/Stores/timerStore.js Module build failed:
>   ReferenceError: [BABEL]
>   /Users/shooshte/PersonalProjects/teaTimer/src/Stores/timerStore.js:
>   Unknown option:
>   /Users/shooshte/PersonalProjects/teaTimer/node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.js.extras.
>   Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information
>   about options.
>
> A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration
>   options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:
>
> Invalid:   `{ presets: [{option: value}] }` Valid:   `{ presets:
>   [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
>
> For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see
>   http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options. (While
>   processing preset:
>   "/Users/shooshte/PersonalProjects/teaTimer/node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.js")
>       at Array.map (native)  @ ./src/index.js 15:18-48

Comment: same problem; no answers I guess!